# How do you omit a row from a chart so it doesn't appear in the excel graph

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a chart of information

[image: attached image]

which has 3 rows against each month of the year: Actual Sales, Baseline Sales and the different between the Actual & Baseline (so the third row is a sum).

I want to exclude the sum row for each month from the chart because it's irrelevant.

I have gone to Select Data Source and unticked the box in the Horizontal Axis label which shows the graph correctly, however when I next visit the graph it's jumped back to include that row again. Please can someone advise in simple language how to exclude this row for each month.
[image: Data for graph]

Comment: Maybe hiding the rows?

Comment: Mmmm, yes thank you,  that would work for the graph but we want to see the row of figures in the chart... Is there something about adding a 'white space' figure??

Comment: Wait, what? you want to omit the row in the chart, but you want to see it in the chart? How does that work?

Comment: No, we want to see the row in the chart (which is the difference between actual sales and a target) but we don't wnt to see that row in the graph because it's irrelevant... Does that make sense??

Comment: Select the chart and go to Chart Design- Select Data, modify the data.